# Creating and print Count in Table SQL

Tags: mysql, sql, postgresql

I am trying to print out the count as an extra column with the following query:

```
SELECT Member.memberID, Member.lastname, Member.firstname
FROM CurrentLoan 
    JOIN Member ON CurrentLoan.memberID = Member.memberID
WHERE CurrentLoan.memberID = Member.memberID
GROUP BY Member.lastname
HAVING COUNT( Member.memberID) ;
```

Right now, I have it set up to where the query takes the memberID from the CurrentLoan table, gets the corresponding first and last name from the Member table and lists them, but I need to get the count of each member (as in how many books the member has taken) 
Any tips?

Comment: Are you using MySQL or Postgresql?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your current query seems on the right track, but if you want the count of each member's books, then you'll have to select it:

```
SELECT
    m.memberID,
    m.lastname,
    m.firstname,
    COUNT(c.memberID) AS book_cnt
FROM Member m
LEFT JOIN CurrentLoan c
    ON m.memberID = c.memberID
GROUP BY
    m.memberID;
```

The count expression `COUNT(c.memberID)` is important, because it is counting records from the joining table `CurrentLoan`.  In the edge case that a member has no books taken out, this count expression would report zero.  Also note that we left join here to make sure that we don't drop any members who happen to have no books at the moment.

Comment: I have tried your solution, but there seems to be a syntax issue on the COUNT line  #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'COUNT(c.memberID) AS book_cnt
FROM Member m
LEFT JOIN CurrentLoan c
    ON m.' at line 5. Any suggestions on that?

Comment: @JaneDean Sorry, there was a missing comma after `m.firstname` in the select clause.  Try the update.